# Can the Android SpeechRecognizer class recognize syllables/phones and not just complete words?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm trying to build a little app that can recognize syllables, like `Ah`, `Oh`, `Uh`, `Eh` etc.

I thought to use the Android SpeechRecognizer class, but it works fine just for complete word, not to syllables.

For example, if you say the sound of the letter `A`, let say like `Ehi` it will display `Hey`. But if you say `Ah` it not display anything.

Do you have any suggestions?
Does this class have any function that can help me with my purpose?
I prefer answers about the Android SpeechRecognizer and not about another tool right now.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like that in Android's SpeechRecognizer, but you can take a look at the [pocketsphinx-android](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/) project which seems to be a perfect match for your problem, because it among others it supports [allphone](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/phonemerecognition/) mode in which separate phonemes are recognized.

Comment: The pocket-sphinx also "trying" to complete the vowel, or to present the letter that sound like the vowel.
And the results for words is much better in the android SpeechRecognizer.

Comment: @nirKa I updated the answer with the additional info that should help you to solve the problem. Please, accept my asnwer if you found it helpful. Thank you!